# How to convert an MsAcess database into a web form?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, vba, merge

I have some VBA code that allows me to enter data into a form in Access, and then the VBA code takes that data and performs a "mail merge" type function into a word document.

I want to do this same thing now with MySQL. Is there a way to query data from MySQL and merge it into a word document? The VBA Script that I would like to convert to a web-based version is below. Thanks!

```
Public Sub Command21_Click()

        Dim db As Database
        Set db = CurrentDb

       Dim Word As Object
       Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        Dim rst As Recordset
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("qryNOH")

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With objWord

'make the application visible
Word.Visible = True


'Define First and Last name strings for searching Query1
Dim IDText As String

IDText = "Me.IDText"

' Open the document.
.Documents.Open ("C:\test.docx")

'Set rst to the record you have selected
rst.FindLast "[IDtext] = '" & IDText & "'"

'Header

.Activedocument.FormFields("entry1").Result = rst("entry1")
.Activedocument.FormFields("entry2").Result = rst("entry2")
.Activedocument.FormFields("entry3").Result = rst("entry3")

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this question isn't well-structured for a good answer on this site. This will probably need to be split into a few questions. For example, to improve a first question, ask how to structure a MySQL table like your Access table, and include the table schema you have in Access. If you already have a table, then start asking about creating PHP to see data in that table. Btw - yes, Word can connect with MySQL as an ODBC source and do a mail merge.

Comment: Are you trying to do a mail merge from a back end script? I think that would be the easiest thing for you to do instead of exporting to word to then later do a mail merge. If that is what you are attempting to do, then I might be able to write an answer.

Comment: @McStuffins, the first one. Right, I'm just using the word "mail merge" as a short form. What I really want is I want data from my back end query to push into pre-configured spots in my word document. Like, "my name is_______" and have the name field fill that blank. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does it matter what language it is in? I already have some code written in Node.JS if you want to see it. I could probably translate it to PHP fairly quickly though. The language doesn't really matter to me. I would have given you some PHP code if that was the only tag that you provided...

Comment: Does the output have to be a word document? How about if there is some code that will check send it for you?

Answer (score 0):

So, I made this quick thing in PHP. I tested it and all works. You should check it out at: https://github.com/McStuffins/Replacer

It will take the content from a file and replace it with given value. Make sure the keys are the same as they are in the file. I did not go through with setting up a database connection etc. If you would like to do that, then go ahead and go to: `src/Database/Config.php` and add the MySQL credentials to the file. My code is already accepting the constants. To use the database connection, it would be something like this:

```
$send = new Replacer\Database\Send(Replacer\Database\Command("SELECT * FROM sometable"));
$content = $send->get()->fetch('obj'); //Check src/Database/Content for accepted values on fetch
```

I did not go through with sending the email, but I am sure that it will not be too bad. If you want me to include it, then I will without a problem. Just let me know. I hope this helps!

Comment: Whoa! This is really amazing! I'm such a damn beginner that I think it's going to take a moment for me to unpack what the hell just happened, but this is huge.

Comment: If you need any help, I am willing to help you out for sure! I hope you enjoy the quick package I made!

Comment: I am not sure if it is exactly what you were looking for, but I am sure that if you tell me what else you need i'll add it without a problem.

Comment: @KirbyPunch If you think this answer was helpful, please click the up arrow next to the answer. Also, If it was the correct answer, can you please click the check mark under the voting area? I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!